# Pseudo-element positioned outside parent line wraps early

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've created a simple tooltip system for my website using a tooltip attribute and an ::after pseudoelement. Unfortunately, because the pseudoelement is positioned outside of its parent, it wants to wrap to the size of the parent element. Is there a way to prevent this without preventing wrapping altogether?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v5zhf2nu/1/

CSS:

```
[tooltip]
{
    position: relative;
    cursor: help;
}

[tooltip]::after
{
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(tooltip);
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;

    margin-left: 3px;
    background-color: #111111;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 3;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

[tooltip]:hover::after
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span tooltip = "This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early.">Mouse over me!</span>
```

Comment: Why don't you specify width for  `[tooltip]:hover::after`?

Comment: Because the tooltip's width can vary based on the amount of text.

Comment: Then, when do you want it to wrap?

Comment: When it reaches the max-width. That may not have been included in the fiddle.

Comment: @Flaxbeard include `max-width` and `min-width`

Comment: I updated the fiddle to include max-width. What would the min-width be?

Comment: Don't use max-width nor min-width - not needed with position relative. https://jsfiddle.net/v5zhf2nu/2/

Comment: See my comment on your answer - this doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the element relatively positioned. This way the containing block of the pseudo-element will be the viewport (or, hopefully, a wide enough element).

```css
[data-tooltip] { position: static; } /* default value */
```

Don't set the `left` property of the pseudo-element. `auto` will compute to the static position, which is the end of the element because it's an `::after` pseudo-element.

```css
[data-tooltip]::after { left: auto; } /* default value */
```

Use some margin instead of `top`, e.g.

```css
[data-tooltip]::after {
  top: auto; /* default value */
  margin-top: .75em;
}
```

The width of the pseudo-element won't be limited by the width of the element, only by the viewport (or the nearest positioned ancestor). You can reduce (but not increase) that limit by using `max-width`:

```css
[data-tooltip]::after { max-width: 1000px; }
```

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  cursor: help;
}
[data-tooltip]::after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  margin-top: .75em;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<span data-tooltip="This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early.">Mouse over me!</span>
<br /><br /><br />
<span data-tooltip="This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. ">Mouse over me!</span>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set `right` to a small enough value, at least minus the maximum width minus paddings, borders and margins:

```css
right: -1015px;
```

If you don't want to do the calculations, you can use a tiny value like `-100000000000px`, but then you will need `max-width`. If you used the exact value you can remove `max-width` if you want

```css
max-width: -1000px;
```

Finally, use one of these:

```css
width: fit-content;
width: max-content;
```

Note they are not widely supported yet, so you may need vendor prefixes.

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
}
[data-tooltip]::after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  right: -100000000000px; /* Tiny value */
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<span data-tooltip="This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early.">Mouse over me!</span>
<br /><br /><br />
<span data-tooltip="This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. This is some information! Unfortunately, it seems to want to line break very early. ">Mouse over me!</span>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like max-content or fit-content will work on any IE/Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
[tooltip]::after
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

With:

```
[tooltip]::after
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
```

Also, I don't think you need the max-width.

https://jsfiddle.net/v5zhf2nu/2/

Comment: This causes jittery behavior when the tooltip wraps (ie, setting max-width to 200). It also will break page flow if there is content after the text with tooltip. The max-width is needed in order to wrap very long tooltips.